# How to properly specialize std::swap for my types?

Tags: c++, std, swap, template-specialization

After I've managed to overload `std::swap` for my class type now I want to specialize it rather than overload it since the standard allows adding template specializations to namespace `std`. Here is my example:

```
class Foo{
public:
    Foo(){
        std::cout << "Foo()\n";
    }
    Foo(Foo const&){
        std::cout << "Foo(Foo const&)\n";
    }
    Foo(Foo&&){
        std::cout << "Foo(Foo&&)\n";
    }
    Foo& operator=(Foo const&){
        std::cout << "operator=(Foo const&)\n";
        return *this;
    }
    Foo& operator=(Foo&&){
        std::cout << "operator=(Foo&&)\n";
        return *this;
    }
    ~Foo(){
        std::cout << "~Foo()\n";
    }
};

class VecFoo;
namespace std{
    template <>
    void swap<VecFoo>(VecFoo&, VecFoo&);
}

class VecFoo{
    Foo* pFoo_ = new Foo[10];
    template<>
    friend void std::swap<VecFoo>(VecFoo&, VecFoo&);
};

template <>
void std::swap<VecFo>(VecFoo& lhs, VecFoo& rhs){
    std::cout << "template <> void std::swap(VecFoo&, VecFoo&)\n";
    std::swap(lhs.pFoo_, rhs.pFoo_);
}


int main(){

    VecFoo vf1, vf2;
    using std::swap;
    swap(vf1, vf2);

}
```

- I don't know why it doesn't compile and I get an error: `/usr/include/c++/10/type_traits|2195|  required by substitution of ‘template<class ... _Cond> using _Require = std::__enable_if_t<std::__and_< <template-parameter-1-1> >::value> [with _Cond = {std::__not_<std::__is_tuple_like<VecFoo> >, std::is_move_constructible<VecFoo>, std::is_move_assignable<VecFoo>}]’|`

So what is the problem here and how could I correctly specialize it?

- P.S: please don't argue about RAII that I am not achieving in my class `VecFoo` and the memory leak there because it is not that my problem here.

Comment: The compiler is not being mega-clear, but it's still telling you exactly what's wrong. Your class `VecFoo` is failing certain checks that are required to pass. I don't recall which of the other **2** questions you've asked about this exact problem has the answer, but one of them does. To address your postscript, the issues you know you have are part of the reason it's failing. So, yes, the bad code is part of the problem you're having.

Answer (score 4):

This is pretty simple really.
You don't need the template but you do need to be in the correct namespace.

```
namespace std {
void swap(VecFoo& lhs, VecFoo& rhs) {
    std::cout << "void swap(VecFoo&, VecFoo&)\n";
    //do your custom swap here!!!
}
}
```

Comment: But this is not a specialization, it is just an overload. I want to specialize it not overload it.

Comment: The difference in general between specialize, overload and override is minor. This would be my preferred way.

Comment: Overloads in std:: are explicitely prohibited by the standard, while specializing a std:: template function is allowed under some conditions. So to be pedantic, that's a major difference (undefined behavior / standard violation vs valid implementation)

Answer (score 1):

`std::move` requires the class to be move-assignable and move-constructible, but the class `VecFoo` is not any of them.

You added a bunch of method to support these constraints in the class `Foo`, which didn't requires any (you are swapping pointers).

Also, there is a typo in the swap declaration: it says `std::swap<VecFo>` instead of `std::swap<VecFoo>`.

Finally, I would recommend NOT using `friend`. Just add a method `swap` to the class and put the logic there.

Comment: Althought `VecFoo` doesn't obey the rule of 3/5/0 and won't behave well with move or copy, as far as the compiler is concerned it is move constructible and it is move assignable. The error message is due to the fact that `VecFoo` is an incomplete type at the point where its move semantics are checked by the compiler.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Sounds so interesting! would you elaborate an example?

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa I'm not sure which part you are asking me to elaborate on.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: I mean could you make my program works. I only want to specialize `std::swap` for my data type `VecFoo` not overloading it. Thank you.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Amazing! I've made `VecFoo` a `struct` (public access specification)  and removed the `swap` friend function declaration and now it works fine. That means s you said it was a problem of incomplete type. So now could you figure it out how to achieve the same thing with a `class` not a `struct`? Thank you!

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa `struct` is the same as `class` but with implicit `public:`. You can provide a public `swap` member function and use that you won't need a `friend` declaration.